# Word order in: "Some things I couldn't distinguish..."

Tags: word-order

The standard word order of a negative sentence:

S + AUX. VERB + MAIN VERB

The sentence:

> **Some things I couldn't distinguish**; consequently I....

Is it kind of inversion or just wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to say? Right now, this isn't a sentence... "There are/were some things I couldn't distinguish" perhaps?

Comment: It's fine to "front" a direct obj to the initial position. Such as "Some things you like, some things you don't". But this contruction is rare or rather literary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider there to be an implicit "there are" or "there were" at the beginning of that sentence, and others like it. Or you might consider it inversion; there are lots of reasons, for style or tone, or to subtly shift meaning, that word order changes in English. It's nowhere near as free as in Latin, say, but it can be very flexible.